# Android/ios: Titanium Appcelerator horizontal scrolling

Tags: android, ios, iphone, titanium, horizontal-scrolling

I am designing a view using Titanium Appcelerator for Android/ios.I need to design a time picker (horizontal). I have designed the view that is horizontal and entered values in it. 
[image]

But Dont know how to pick values that are perfectly under the arrow. And how the last number will come to center(under the arrow).
Please guide..

CODE:

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'});
var scrollAlbums = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
   bottom: 10,
   contentHeight: Ti.UI.SIZE, 
   contentWidth: Ti.UI.SIZE, 
   height: 95,
   layout: 'horizontal',
   showHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
   showVerticalScrollIndicator: true, 
   scrollType: 'horizontal',
    horizontalWrap: false,
   width: Ti.UI.FILL 
});
var data=[];
var circle=[];
for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
    circle[i] = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text:i,
        height:50,
        width:50,   
        borderRadius:25,
        backgroundColor:'#336699'});
    scrollAlbums.add(circle[i]);
}
win1.add(scrollAlbums);
```

Comment: Do you already have some code?

Comment: You could check out paginated scrolling. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView

Comment: Code of your existing work would help.

Comment: @RobinEllerkmann :  i had finished the scroll. But imagine the problem related with the above image, that how can i pick the number when it is scrolled to the center of the view,.?

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to log the middle number when scrolling ends:

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'});
var scrollAlbums = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
   bottom: 10,
   contentHeight: Ti.UI.SIZE, 
   contentWidth: Ti.UI.SIZE, 
   height: 95,
   layout: 'horizontal',
   showHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
   showVerticalScrollIndicator: true, 
   scrollType: 'horizontal',
    horizontalWrap: false,
   width: Ti.UI.FILL 
});
var circleWidth = 50;
function pick(e) {
  if (e.type === 'dragend' && e.decelerate) {
    return;
  }
  console.info('Number: ' + Math.round((e.source.contentOffset.x + (e.source.size.width / 2)) / circleWidth));
}
scrollAlbums.addEventListener('scrollend', pick);
scrollAlbums.addEventListener('dragend', pick);
var data=[];
var circle=[];
for(var i=0;i<20;i++){
    circle[i] = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
        text:i,
        height:circleWidth,
        width:circleWidth,   
        borderRadius:circleWidth/2,
        backgroundColor:'#336699'});
    scrollAlbums.add(circle[i]);
}
win1.add(scrollAlbums);
win1.open();
```

You need to listen to both `scrollend` and `dragend` because `scrollend` will only fire if `dragend` was decelerating. Then with the offset of the scrollView plus half of its total width and the width of the circles you can calculate the middle number.

But like Robin says, you better use ScrollableView and play with `hitRect` and `clipViews` to show not just the selected page (number) but also a few right and left of it.

Comment: the listeners doesnt work..
scrollAlbums.addEventListener('scrollend', pick);
scrollAlbums.addEventListener('dragend', pick);

Comment: How do you mean it doesn't work? I tested the exact pasted code here and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I tries exactly your code without editing anything, But the scrollAlbums doesn't listen anything and didn't print anything in console too. so only got confused..

Comment: What are the specifics of the environment you tested it in? Ti SDK version, iOS SDK version, iOS Sim/device version...

Comment: Tested in Ti 3.5.0 and android 4.4(Kitkat)

Comment: I have tested with the same configuration and it works for me. Very odd!

Comment: adding a comment for anyone else who finds this search as I did.  The reason why this did not work for Ganesh is that only the scroll event works on Android.  Quote from the appcelerator docs;

"Only the scroll event exists for the ScrollableView on Android. To support others, child views may be added to pages, and event listeners added to these views instead of the pages themselves."